# Проблема с REST-api WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api, rest

При POST-запросе к /media/, то есть загрузке медиафайла, вылетает исключение TimeoutError, мол не загружена картинка. В итоге, несмотря на эту ошибку, эта картинка все равно появляется в медиафайлах на вордпрессе, но на самом сайте не выводится.

Comment: Спасибо что сообщил. Теперь исправь пост, задав ВОПРОС. И так, чтобы его поняли.

Comment: @SeVlad ну там же я написал, что картинка на сайт не выводится, не смотря на то, что она загрузилась после появления ошибки.